# Do I have to include every method in an interface?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, interfaces

I'm using a 3rd party contract in one of my contracts.  I've created an interface for the 3rd party, do I have to include every external method in the interface, or just the ones that I need to use in my contract?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum is the functions *your contract* needs. Apart from possible code organization concerns on your side, there is no reason to include unused functions.

Hope it helps